# MVC 5- changing code infrastructure from old Forms authentication to OWIN forms authentication

Tags: c#-4.0, owin, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to migrate an old .NET 3.5, MVC 1 project to a new .NET 4.5 MVC 5 project. I have run into a road block where there is old security/authentication infrastructure in place and I am not quite sure on how to change it over to OWIN claims based authentication. I am still trying to maintain FormsAuthentication with OWIN. A couple of classes:

**DomainPrincipal.cs**

```
public sealed class DomainPrincipal : MarshalByRefObject, IPrincipal
{
    private readonly IIdentity _identity;
    private readonly User _user;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="DomainPrincipal"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="identity">The identity.</param>
    /// <param name="user">The user.</param>
    public DomainPrincipal(IIdentity identity, User user)
    {
        _identity = identity;
        _user = user;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the user.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The <see cref="User"/> associated with the current principal.</value>
    public User User
    {
        get { return _user; }
    }

    #region IPrincipal Members

    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether the current principal belongs to the specified role.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// <c>true</c> if the current principal is a member of the specified role; otherwise <c>false</c>.
    /// </returns>
    /// <param name="roleName">The name of the role for which to check membership. </param>
    public Boolean IsInRole(String roleName)
    {
        return User.HasPrivilege(roleName);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the identity of the current principal.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value></value>
    /// <returns>The <see cref="T:System.Security.Principal.IIdentity"/> object associated with the current principal.</returns>
    public IIdentity Identity
    {
        get { return _identity; }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

**WebFormsAuthenticatedContext.cs** - uses DomainPrincipal class to implement AuthenticatedContext for a forms authentication environment.

```
public sealed class WebFormsAuthenticatedContext : AuthenticatedContext
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the current user.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The current user.</value>
    /// <remarks>Determines the current user from the user principal of the current <see cref="HttpContext"/>.</remarks>
    public User User
    {
        get { return IsValid ? ((DomainPrincipal)HttpContext.Current.User).User : null; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a value indicating whether the <see cref="User"/> property is currently valid.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    ///     <c>true</c> if the <see cref="User"/> property is valid; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
    /// </value>
    public Boolean IsValid
    {
        get { return HttpContext.Current != null && HttpContext.Current.User is DomainPrincipal; }
    }
}
```

**ServiceAuthenticatedContext.cs** - Implements AuthenticatedContext for a WCF service environment.

```
public class ServiceAuthenticatedContext : AuthenticatedContext
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the user DAO.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The user DAO.</value>
    public UserDao UserDao { get; set; }

    #region AuthenticatedContext Members

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the current user.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The current user.</value>
    /// <remarks>Determines the user identity from the current <see cref="ServiceSecurityContext"/>.</remarks>
    public User User
    {
        get
        {
            const string AuthorizationContextKey = "DomainPrincipal";

            AuthorizationContext authorizationContext = ServiceSecurityContext.Current.AuthorizationContext;
            User user;

            if (authorizationContext.Properties.ContainsKey(AuthorizationContextKey))
            {
                user = authorizationContext.Properties[AuthorizationContextKey] as User;
            }
            else
            {
                string username = ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity.Name;
                user = UserDao.GetByUsername(username);
                authorizationContext.Properties.Add(AuthorizationContextKey, user);
            }
            return user;
        }
    }

    public String Username { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a value indicating whether the <see cref="User"/> property is currently valid.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    ///     <c>true</c> if the <see cref="User"/> property is valid; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
    /// </value>
    public bool IsValid
    {
        get { return ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity != null && ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity.IsAuthenticated; }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

I am now looking at achieving something similar using OWIN, signing the user in like so:

```
// Log user in
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] 
                    {
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, model.Username),
                    },
                    DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                    ClaimTypes.Name, ClaimTypes.Role);

            Authentication.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                IsPersistent = model.RememberMe
            }, identity);
```

and using the custom DomainPrincipal class in place as a ClaimsPrincipal instead (changing it accordingly) and changing WebFormsAuthenticatedContext and ServiceAuthenticatedContext classes to work with this new DomainPrincipal and OWIN security model.

Is this possible to do? Or would I need to revamp the whole authentication infrastructure completely?

Your help and advice would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/07/03/understanding-owin-forms-authentication-in-mvc-5/)
It may give you more insight into how to implement Owin authentication.

To answer your question, if all you want to use a custom principal for handling roles - DomainPrinicpal(extending the IPrincipal), you just need to replace the HttpContext.Current.User as Request.GetOwinContext().Request.User in the WebFormsAuthenticatedContext class.